# c builtin data types detect into input text file with python

Tags: python, file, built-in-types

I have a input text file there has some c language code. I want to detect from that file how much c data types are included there and it will be saved another output file but first want to show my input text then under this text my another filtering code will show into output file.

In this case first i have opened a file with 'a' or append mode but it's working opposite.

## My Code

```
keyword = ['auto', 'double', 'int', 'struct', 'break', 'else', 'long', 
       'switch', 'case', 'enum', 'register', 'typedef', 'char', 
       'extern', 'return', 'union', 'const', 'float', 'short', 
       'unsigned', 'continue', 'for','signed', 'void', 'default', 
       'goto', 'sizeof', 'volatile','do', 'if', 'static', 'while']
f_read = open('input.txt', mode='r')
f_write =  open('output.txt', 'a')
for i in f_read.read():
    f_write.write(i)
f_read.close()
empty = []
for key in keyword:
    with open('input.txt', mode='r') as read_fp:
        if key in read_fp.read():
            if key in empty:
                empty[key] += 1
            with open('output.txt', 'w') as write_fp:
                empty.append(key)
                write_fp.write(' \n'.join(empty))
f_write.close()
```

## my expect output text file will show such like following

```
My input text file all code 

      then

Data Types-------------Count

int                       1

float                     3

return                    1
```

> into my input file has some c code after filtering it'll show 1 int, 3
>   float and 1 return data types.

Thanks

Comment: you should edit your formatting, this is all over the place

Comment: Your &quot;empty&quot; var is a list, it shall be a dict. And you shall open your output.txt file in append mode, in the current code, it is erased at each iteration of the loop. I suggest you to open all your files outside the loop (to avoid unnecessary file access)

Comment: But if my var is as dict then append doesn't work because of append is not attribute of dict

Comment: In this case what can i do?

Comment: To insert a new key with value 1 in a dict you can use var[key] = 1

Comment: I'used this before and it's working but for only command interface and can not put into output.txt file. Main trouble here. According to your words when i'm opening file outside the loop then i've to being close my input.txt file in the last and for this reason  write mod working simply, as a result everything has remaining save individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print a dict (I'm not using any in my answer code)

```
for k,v in iteritems(mydict):
   print ('{}\t{}'.format(k,v))
```

my solution to your problem is a lot more different that what you have try but shall meet your requirements  (and does not handle if keyword are commented...)

```
import re

keyword = ['auto', 'double', 'int', 'struct', 'break', 'else', 'long',
       'switch', 'case', 'enum', 'register', 'typedef', 'char',
       'extern', 'return', 'union', 'const', 'float', 'short',
       'unsigned', 'continue', 'for','signed', 'void', 'default',
       'goto', 'sizeof', 'volatile','do', 'if', 'static', 'while']

read_fp = open('input.txt', 'r')
write_fp = open('output.txt', 'w')
content = read_fp.read()
for key in keyword:
    # here you have to count each occurrence of your keyword in content, I suggest you use regex :
    # the surrounding \W insure that you only match the keywords (e.g int doc_page = 0; shall not match
    # 'do'
    matches = re.findall('\W{}\W'.format(key), content)
    if matches:
       write_fp.write ('{}\t{}\n'.format(key, len(matches)))
read_fp.close()
write_fp.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Nico I have to try it.